# window.close() problems

Tags: javascript, firefox, mobile, opera

This works in IE, Chrome and Safari.

How Can I make this work in FF and Opera? Is this going to work in Mobile devices like android or iOS? Or it depends on the browser you are using?

```
var answer = confirm ("La lectura del código ha FALLADO. Pulse CANCELAR para volver a intentar");
if (!answer)
window.close();

else(answer)
window.location="http://www.google.com/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code

```
else(answer)
```

is not valid syntax and should just be

```
else
```

also

```
window.location="http://www.google.com/"
```

should be

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = confirm("La lectura del código ha FALLADO. Pulse CANCELAR para volver a intentar");
if (!answer) {
window.close();

else {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"
}
```